# PHP changing old mysql_query to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have some old mysql_query queries in my code which i want to convert in to PDO but am struggling to get to work.

my original code was:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE people SET price='$price', contact='$contact', fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username' ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

now i am trying:

```
$sql = "UPDATE people SET price='$price', contact='$contact', fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username'";
$q   = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");
```

but can't seem to get it to work, any ideas?

UPDATED CODE:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);


 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the   database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
  {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $fname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']));
 $lname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']));
 $contact = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact']));
 $price = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['price']));


 // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($fname == '' || $lname == '' || $contact == '' || $price == '' )
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 //error, display form
 renderForm($id, $fname, $lname, $contact, $price, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];

 $query = "UPDATE people 
         SET price=?, 
             contact=?, 
             fname=?, 
             lname=? 
          WHERE id=? AND 
                username=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $price);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $contact);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $lname);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $id);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $username);    
$stmt->execute();


 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
header("Location: view.php"); 
}
```

Comment: If you're going to switch to PDO, which is a great idea, be sure to use SQL placeholders. Your old example is typical of `mysql_query` where it's likely vulnerable to severe SQL injection problems. As always, what errors are you getting? "Can't get it to work" is not a useful diagnostic.

Comment: Despite the improvements, your method should work. Can you show the full code, from where you start initiating `$conn`?

Comment: sorry i should have been more specific, i have an edit form which allows users to edit adverts they have posted, when they click on an ad to edit it comes up with the form and the previous values are already echo'ed in to the text boxes from my database. This still works fine (it uses another query), now when I try and sumbit the form it comes up with "mysql_real_escape_string" error which to me suggests that the form is sumbiting blank data so to speak? so i'm not sure whether my PDO query is at fault as it was working fine with the old mysql_query code, thanks for your help!!

Comment: yes will include the full code in the question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For more information visit this link: **[PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**

based on your example,

```
<?php

    $query = "UPDATE people 
             SET price=?, 
                 contact=?, 
                 fname=?, 
                 lname=? 
              WHERE id=? AND 
                    username=?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $price);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $contact);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $fname);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $lname);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $username);    
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

**[PDO Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)**

[image]

Comment: thankyou for your reply! i have used this method but i am still getting the mysql_real_escape_string error? could this be because i have defined my variables as  "$fname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']));" is this necessary when using PDO or do you think it is something else?

Comment: @NeilKumar try removing that, PDO will automatically do the escaping for you. `$fname = $_POST['fname'];`

Comment: okay now i get Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in... any ideas what this means?

Comment: @NeilKumar i think it's because you are using `$db` instead of `$conn`. change `$db->prepare($query);` to `$conn->prepare($query);`

Answer (score 5):

Note that when working with the mysql driver for PDO you **always** have to [disable emulated prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php):

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'UPDATE people SET';
$sql.= ' price = :price,';
$sql.= ' contact = :contact,';
$sql.= ' fname = :fname,';
$sq;.= ' lname = :lname';
$sql.= ' WHERE id= :id AND username = :username';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':price' => $price,
    ':contact' => $contact,
    ':fname' => $fname,
    ':lname' => $lname,
    ':id' => $id,
    ':username' => $username,
));
```

As you can see I have used named parameters, because when you have lots of them it is imho way clearer what you are doing.

*Note: that [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell) is currently working on [getting the default to always use real prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/508666), but until that (which may take some while) you always have to disable them for mysql.*

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to use PDO, you need to look at [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) otherwise you're losing the security that PDO is offering and retaining the SQL Injections. So, given your example:

```
$conn = new PDO(/*connection info*/);

$query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE people "
                      . "SET    price    = :price, "
                      . "       contact  = :contact, "
                      . "       fname    = :fname, "
                      . "       lname    = :lname "
                      . "WHERE  id       = :id "
                      . "  AND  username = :username");
$result = $query->execute(array(
  ':price'    => $price,
  ':contact'  => $contact,
  ':fname'    => $fname,
  ':lname'    => $lname,
  ':id'       => $id,
  ':username' => $username
));
```

That's more the lax way, but you can also [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and be explicit as to the data type it's expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Few things you have to be clear while using PDO extension is that there are multiple ways to get things done.

The way you are currently using being one of them including few more. However it is always a good idea to [bind parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) separately, because this prevents many problems like SQL Injection and many more.

Other important things to look at are [`statement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), [`prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

```
$conn = new PDO("...."); //Creating the handler

//Create the statement
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE people SET price = :price, contact = :contact, fname = :fname, lname = :lname WHERE id= :id AND username = :username");

// Bind the params
$stml -> bindParam(":contact", $contact, PDO::PARAM_STR); //This way you can also define the DATATYPE of the parameter

//Execute
$stmt -> execute(array(
   ":price" => $price, //another way of binding the params
   ":fname" => $fname, 
   ":lname" => $lname,
   ":id" => $id, 
   ":username" => $username));
```