# How can combine two different MySQL connections in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection, mysql-connect

I followed many tutorials to set up a registration form on my site.
Now I added file upload on a extra site and I'm not sure how to combine the MySQL connections. I want to make a PDO Solution.

`database.php` **(MySQL Connection #1) for register form.**

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = '';
$database = 'auth';

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die( "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

`dbconfig.php` **(MySQL Connection #1) for file upload.**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "xxx";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "dbtuts";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('cannot connect to the server'); 
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('database selection problem');
?>
```

I'm working with the Online IDE www.c9.io and using Bootstrap.

Comment: What **precisely** do you mean by _combine 2 connections_

Comment: If you want to use PDO for both connections you will have to rewrite all the `mysql_` extension functions into PDO code. Its not just a case of changing the connection method

Comment: there is a "connection to sql"-file from the first tutorial "making a registration form" and a second "making a file upload"". 
sry my english is not that good i hope you understand me. :(

Comment: be warned that mysql_ functions are deprecated an may not work in PHP 7. You should update them at least to mysqli_ (with the i on the end) functions. Anyway the mysql_connect functions returns you a resource which you can keep into memory and use as parameter calling other mysql_ functions

Comment: *"i want to make a PDO Solution"* - So why the `mysql_*`? and why 2 connections?

Comment: Fred -ii- this is a code from 1 tutorial i  just copy & paste it.

Comment: @sinankarateke what's the end goal?

Comment: RiggsFolly this is the question how should the pdo code look like for 'dbconfig.php'?

Comment: I don't see the reason of using 2 separate connections; just use the same one and change the database when querying.

Comment: i didnt expected that the answers flow so quick. so, puh. i'll now delete 'dbconfig.php' the one with "mysql_connect" and correct the code who are related to 'dbconfig.php'.

Comment: edit: and also drop the 'dbtuts' database and move the table in the first database 'auth'.

Comment: _how should the pdo code look like for 'dbconfig.php_ Exactly the same as the PDO one. Infact you could `include 'database.php';` in the second script. **But all the other mysql_ code will need rewriting** You cannot connect with PDO and execute `mysql_` functions

Comment: @RiggsFolly i found a thread who is answering me how to do the mysql_code rewriting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310238/php-changing-old-mysql-query-to-pdo) and i also think this was my question ._.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i found your last answer useful but i also appreciate all you guys how helped me to figure it out and giving "food for taught".  i try to translate from german to english so good i can right now ^^

Answer (score 2):

You don't need it. Just create a **single** connection to a single database and then use it all the way through. *Especially if it's your first attempt to work with PHP.*

Comment: Surely this qualifies as a comment not an answer. Replacing the connection code will only make the `mysql_` function calls later in the OP's other script fail. At least a small mention of this would be useful!